# comparision between sql datetime and Datetime.Now

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

What I am trying is to compare the time between sql table datetime value and `Datetime.Now`.
The values in sql table has no seconds (i-e 1900-01-01 00:23:00.000) 
and my `Datetime.Now` value is taking seconds part also (i-e 1900-01-01 00:23:47.000).
When I try to compare these two time due to seconds part from `Datetime.Now` it jumps to the next if else condition

Here is my code

```
if (MedRmndrDat.Valid)
{
    foreach (var MedReminder in MedRmndrDat.Data)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(MedReminder.EveryDay))
        {
            if (DateTime.Now >= MedReminder.MedicationIntakeStartDate)
            {
       **//it is not performing this if condition, it keeps jumping on next condition***                                  
                if (DateTime.Now==MedReminder.TimeSchedule1) 

                {
                    MessageSenderUtility.Sendsms(MobileNum, item.UserName, MedReminder.Description, MedReminder.MedicationName, MedReminder.Quantity.ToString());
                }

                else if (DateTime.Now == MedReminder.TimeSchedule2)
                {
                   ... Some code ...
                }

                else if (DateTime.Now == MedReminder.TimeSchedule3)
                {
                       ... Some code ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to compare them?

Comment: When you debug your code, are you _really_ sure you see those values?

Comment: Yes sql datetime have now seconds but datetime.now has i am pretty sure it is making the condition false @SonerGönül

Comment: @dotctor i want to compare only date and hours and minutes from time

Comment: @Ian thanks it worked

Comment: @SheikhAfham great! Glad to know that. =)

Comment: I think its bad idea to compare times with equality for reminders. You should keep track of last notification you have sent, and compare only with '>' to see if new reminder should be sent. What if this method is called twice within a minute, or not called in exact same minute with a reminder..

Comment: @RamazanBinarbasi i have a scheduler for it. The scheduler will this method at a certain time to check if there is any valid conditions to send the sms to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to strip the seconds and milliseconds off `DateTime.Now` and use that in your comparison.

So you'll have to store the current time in a local variable first:

```
DateTime testTime = DateTime.Now;
testTime = testTime.AddSeconds(-testTime.Second).AddMilliseconds(-testTime.Millisecond);
```

Then use it in your comparisons:

```
if (testTime >= MedReminder.MedicationIntakeStartDate)
{
    if (testTime == MedReminder.TimeSchedule1) 
    {
        ... some code
    }
    else if (testTime == MedReminder.TimeSchedule2)
    {
       ... some code ...
    }
    else if (testTime == MedReminder.TimeSchedule3)
    {
       ... some code ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF this is exactly what i was looking for Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should only declare your `DateTime.Now` **once** and use the declared value through out the process to avoid `DateTime.Now` value to be changed during the process and thus render your comparisons invalid (since they do not compare the same `DateTime`).

```
DateTime dtnow = DateTime.Now; //use dtnow for the subsequent comparison
```

Declare `dtnow` above **before** your **first** `if`.

Secondly, regarding your question, what you can do is by removing the second and millisecond part of the `DateTime` using `Add[Time]` methods in the `DateTime` class. Something like this will do:

```
dtnow = dtnow.AddSeconds(-dtnow.Second).AddMilliseconds(-dtnow.Millisecond); //Note the negative sign
```

This way, you remove the excessive second and millisecond which you do not want to use and you are ready for clean comparison!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property **Date** from DateTime and then **AddHours** and **AddMinutes**

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now;
myDate = myDate.Date.AddHours(myDate.Hour).AddMinutes(myDate.Minute)
```

And then your code will be like this

```
if (MedRmndrDat.Valid)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    now = now.Date.AddHours(now.Hour).AddMinutes(now.Minute)
    foreach (var MedReminder in MedRmndrDat.Data)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(MedReminder.EveryDay))
        {
            if (DateTime.Now >= MedReminder.MedicationIntakeStartDate)
            {
                if (now == MedReminder.TimeSchedule1) 
                {
                    MessageSenderUtility.Sendsms(MobileNum, item.UserName, MedReminder.Description, MedReminder.MedicationName, MedReminder.Quantity.ToString());
                }

                else if (now == MedReminder.TimeSchedule2)
                {
                   ... Some code ...
                }

                else if (now == MedReminder.TimeSchedule3)
                {
                       ... Some code ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work as the data in the table includes hours and minutes.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, it works, the `.Date` property remove the time from the DateTime, it doesn't matter if the date the you got from your database came with time.

Comment: But it won't work as expected if the hours and minutes in the database are important.

Comment: @Alberto Monteiro i want date as well as time also but not the seconds from both sql datetime and datetime.now

Comment: @ChrisF exactly in my program hours and minutes are important but not seconds

Comment: @SheikhAfham Ok, I fixed it

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SheikhAfham It fixed your problem?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro i subtracted the current seconds in addseconds method taking the refrence from your above example